# Is it possible to transition admob ad smoothly onto a new intent/screen?

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I currently have an application that uses Admob for serving ads. When a user click a correct answer the screen transition and then a new intent open up. This then loads the xml file layout again with the ad. When this happens the ad has to reload(it shows blank space for a few seconds then the ad comes up) even though the previous screen had an ad there before. Is it possible so that the ad from the previous screen to transition smoothly into the next screen, without having to wait a few seconds for the new ad to load on the next screen  layout?

Answer (score 0):

Not currently: each AdMob instance is tied to the Activity.

You could possibly use the Fragment interface to essentially tie all your functionality to a single Activity instance and then you wouldn't need to switch to a new Activity and lose the AdMob instance, but I haven't seen anyone who has done this yet.